# C++ namespace name isolation

Tags: design, c++, naming, modules, namespace

It's been considered for a reason, that `using` for namespaces/names is side-effect-prone, and generally, fully qualified names should be preferred.

I've come up with an approach on that, which I couldn't find implemented yet, so I created my own [project](https://github.com/olukyrich/cpp-namespace-util).

Briefly, the idea is to define a set of macro which would unfold into the following structure:

```
namespace your_namespace {
    namespace __local__ {
            //includes and other non-exported names go here
        namespace __exported__ {
            //actual code goes here
        }
    }
    using namespace __local__::__exported__;
}
```

It isolates the contents of `__local__` from `your_namespace`, while keeping them visible to it's logically-actual part.

General usage looks like this:

```
#include <namespace_util.hpp>

NAMESPACE(foo)
//here go using declarations, and the names you don't want to be visible from outside
NAMESPACE_EXPORTS
//here go your namespace members
NAMESPACE_END
```

The implementation:

```
#define NAMESPACE(name)\
    namespace name {\
        namespace __local__ {\

#define NAMESPACE_EXPORTS\
            namespace __exported__ {

#define NAMESPACE_END\
            }\
        }\
        using namespace __local__::__exported__;\
    }
```

Since I'm relatively new to C++, I can't be completely sure about the solution, so I ask the people: please see the (much more detailed) [README](https://github.com/olukyrich/cpp-namespace-util/blob/master/README.md), the [code](https://github.com/olukyrich/cpp-namespace-util/blob/master/namespace_util.hpp), and give your feedback.

Thank you.

Comment: So you are "relatively new to C++" and come up with an approach that you "couldn't find implemented yet." Sounds like this should be on codereview.

Comment: They kicked me in here :)

Comment: "`using` for namespaces/names is side-effect-prone" What is side-effect-prone supposed to mean? `using` just allows you to refer to things without the qualified name, it's perfectly usable in individual translation units, and you can minimize issues by `using` specific functions/classes/etc. rather than the whole namespace (`using namespace` does basically defeat the purpose of namespaces, if that's what you meant). In fact, if you want to do proper ADL with `std::swap` you need `using std::swap` inside your swap implementations.

Comment: >>What is side-effect-prone supposed to mean?>> this have been answered by me across the comments. I will update the post or make a self-answer with the summary soon.

Answer (score 10):

Your approach is not technically wrong (except a minor detail, see footnote) but it goes against established usage patterns and obfuscates code. I.e. it lowers readability and increases the likelihood of errors. That *might* be justified if it is outweighed by a clear and significant advantage somewhere else. And here lies the problem. Sjoerd already pointed it out in his answer, but let me reiterate: Precicely what is the problem you are trying to solve? Why is your solution significantly better than the established one? An advantage is not apparent at all, so considering the drawbacks this approach is not useful.

The most severe problem I see are the NAMESPACE macros. They replace basic structural C++ elements, essentially creating a language inside the language. The structure of namespaces and symbol names inside is a central part of the API a header exposes. Obfuscating that structure makes it much harder to understand what’s going on in that header.

Looking at the pattern itself, I’m still not convinced. You’ve now made it clearer in some comments and your updated question that you want to be able to use names from the `__local__` namespace without qualifying their names and without the transitive effects of `using namespace`. On the one hand that can indeed be a benefit for readability, especially if it avoids awkward line breaks because of long qualified names. On the other hand a specific `using` or `using namespace` inside a function has the same effect where it’s really needed. Also declaring your *external* symbols in a namespace that is a child of an *internal* namespace and then pulling them out of there again with a `using` is not very elegant. All in all I find the pattern not convincing, but mostly harmless (not regarding the macros!).

For comparison: This is the idiomatic pattern to hide private symbols, i.e. a developer familiar with the C++ ecosystem will expect to see it and intuitively know what it means:

```
// some_file.cpp
namespace my_ns {
    namespace {
        // Most private symbols go here.
        const int foo = 1;
    }

    int double_foo() {
        return foo * 2;
    }
}


// some_file.hpp
namespace my_ns {
    namespace detail {
        // Private names that cannot be hidden in the .cpp
        // go here. Other common names for this namespace are:
        // "impl", "implementation", sth with "private"
        const int bar = 2;
    }

    int double_foo();

    // function that cannot be implemented in the .cpp
    template <typename T>
    void add_bar(const T& to) {
        using namespace detail;
        // or use the qualified name instead
        to += bar;
    }
}
```

*Footnote:* Minor technical detail: A lot of underscored names are reserved for the implementation (of the standard). See [the standard](https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard), section [reserved.names] for full details. In your code the double-underscored names are problematic. The be-on-the-safe-side rule is: Do not create your own names starting with an underscore and avoid double underscores altogether.

Comment: 1) There exists the transitive effect of `using` (for names). In my opinion, it can be unwanted in some situations, but there's no clear way to disapply it. That's the problem I'm trying to solve. So, I proposed a pattern (no macro at this point) for that purpose. The pattern itself, in a way, relies on semantic encapsulation (underscored prefix/suffix), a common practice to discourage the unintended usage. In addition, I made a couple of macros to simplify the pattern usage.

Comment: I'm perfectly aware of flaws of macro and underscore encapsulation, yet I think it's the reasonable price for ability to safely use `using` at namespace level + hide the names within a namespace.

Comment: 2) In the following excerpt `foo` actually will have been put into `my_ns`. Anyone can access it like `my_ns::foo`. That's a strange meaning of "private".
```
namespace my_ns {
    namespace {
// Most private symbols go here.
        const int foo = 1;
    }

    int double_foo() {
        return foo * 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: 3) You're right on reserved underscored names. I intentionally used them for the sake of demonstration. They should be changed.

Comment: How about the pattern itself? It can be used without macro, it's not that verbose, and it achieves the effect.

Comment: Using the macro distracted attention away from the underlying technique, for the reasons I mentioned in my answer. In general, if you want to ask about some code style, hiding it behind a macro is a bad approach, because then people have to pre-process your code in their heads before they can think about it.

Comment: I extended my answer to address the pattern itself in more detail together with your 1). Regarding 2): Only everyone inside that specific .cpp file can access `foo`. Because of the anonymous namespace it is not visible anywhere else (Ok, that’s a bit simplified. Look up the [one definition role](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) for the full visibility story). Yes, it’s “global” in that one file, but that’s intentional.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like a wrong approach, for several reasons:

1. The things that you don't want to be "visible" to outside, should not go into headers. Instead they go into anonymous namespace in the source file.
2. Your `__local__` things are still visible, and everyone can access them

Comment: 1. Debatable. What If I design a header-only library, and for the sake of modularity and brevity want to introduce a namespace tree, and import names to use short id's, without being afraid of side-effects?

Comment: 2. That's addressed in README. It's discouraged to use internal namespaces directly. I can't fully restrict it, but common sense should imply not to use something named _______do_not_touch_me______

Comment: @oleg.lukyrych Header only (I guess something like boost) can be done like you explained: things that should not be used is put into such ("implementation") namespace. For normal code, I would avoid it. Regarding the 2nd comment, don't expect people to read README files or comments - they want to use your library without that.

Comment: Well, that doesn't make the approach wrong. By wrong I would mean some technical blunder which leads to real errors. 
Anyway, Speaking on tastes in code design, I find it handy to be able to use short names without side-effects -- that's what this thing is really about.

Comment: >> don't expect people to read README files or comments <<

Semantic encapsulation via prefixing is a widely known thing. And I generally believe the users of such code would read the docs.

Comment: @oleg.lukyrych You are "relatively new to C++." My advice: Accept advice when given, and stop arguing everything.

Comment: @Sjoerd this is ad hominem. I'd love to hear real arguments, that's why I made this post in the first place.

Comment: The "relatively new to C++" is a direct quote from your post. And you're arguing again - proving my point.

Comment: @Sjoerd Ad hominem -- is that you think I should resignedly accept claims from ones who are more experienced/qualified (which is a subject to prove).

Comment: It's an _appeal to authority_, not an _ad hominem_ attack. Both _can_ be fallacious, but if you've explicitly mentioned your lack of experience, then claiming authority due to greater experience isn't necessarily wrong. And, it's not always possible to justify the fruit of experience in a short answer.

Comment: @Useless That's why such unreliable evidence device shouldn't be applied.

Answer (score 6):

What problem do you want to solve? That is completely unclear.

As for your code, if you were a junior assigned to me, I would say:

- Your approach doesn't hide implementation details at all - they are still visible in the header.
- Your approach hides things behind C-style macros, which are considered "avoid whenever possible" by the C++ community. So replacing a solution not using macros with a solution using macros, is going in the wrong direction.
- You state

  > `using` for namespaces/names is side-effect-prone

  but write `using namespace` yourself. So you're inconsistent.

After pointing out those basic mistakes, I wouldn't spend any more time on your code. Instead, I would go back to the main question: **What problem do you want to solve?**

Comment: The very fact that the following code compiles means the existence of side effects.

namespace foo {
    struct A {};
}

namespace bar {
    using namespace foo;
    struct B {
        A a;
    };
}

namespace baz {
    using namespace bar;
    A a;
}

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not in position to answer with the code. I made some examples in my README.

Comment: I know that if you stick with the certain style, it won't be critical. But if you don't want to consider header-only style, imagine the following. You design an ortodox header which contains only definitions, but they're compile-dependent on some external names, which may be complex, and there's many of them. If you introduce the namespace in the header (using directive) -- you get side effects, because header users (let it be only your implementation file) will implicitly get all the names from that namespace

Comment: >>header which contains only definitions>> 
Sorry, I meant declarations, of course.

Comment: @oleg.lukyrych Four comments by you later, and there is still no clear answer to the question "What problem do you want to solve?" If the problem is the supposed "side effect problem" (the transitive effect of `using`): that's by design, and is not considered a problem at all by the C++ community.

Comment: I want to have names introduced by `using` not exposed by the namespace, but still visible inside it.

Comment: You speak for the C++ community? I look into some libraries source, and see endless snakes of fully qualified names. not a problem at all

Comment: Just use the fully qualified name: `namespace::name`. Or use `using namespace::name;` inside the few functions that use it (yes, you can use `using` inside functions).

Comment: Well, apparently the C++ community uses all those "endless snakes of fully qualified names". You're the only one who thinks it's a problem.

Comment: Very nice. Now we've come to what I'm aiming to eliminate. Of course I know how to handle name conflicts, but in large projects you inevitably get significant amount of code duplication that way.

Comment: Isn't that the reason why using directive (applied to names) was introduced to the language -- to allow shorter id's?

Comment: If you want shorter names, use `using sh_nm = long::inner::very_long_name;` Or typedef the long name.

Comment: It's not a problem. Get over it. That's my last advice here. You clearly are not listening to advice - you just want to be confirmed in your believes.

Comment: Again, I'm aware of aliasing :) So what's conceptually bad, besides macro, in what I propose?

Comment: Besides the macro, it's still adding complexity. Since you've consistently refused to provide an example of any code which warrants this complexity, most people are going to say there's no benefit, or insufficient benefit to justify that complexity. Once again, if you do have some _minimal code that demonstrates the problem_, post _that_. You're asking for a judgement call (does A justify B) and not showing A. You could ask _"could any A justify B"_, but that's not an interesting question. You actually asked _"do you think there will often arise As which justify B"_, which is opinion.

Comment: @oleg.lukyrych "I want to have names introduced by `using` not exposed by the namespace, but still visible inside it." Something like the opposite of inline namespaces? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Inline_namespaces

Comment: if I apply `using namespace std;` in an inline namespace, all the `std` names will be put into the outer namespace, and exposed to those who're `using` it. The absence of non-transitive semantics of `using` directive -- is the problem I address.

Comment: @oleg.lukyrych _"So what's conceptually bad, besides macro, in what I propose?"_ That the code that imports the namespace may break when the code within the imported namespace is changed. That doesn't happen (as quickly) when you fully qualify names. See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you really want constructive feedback on this approach, it would have been better to show some actual code that you think benefits from it. Then we'd have something concrete to discuss rather than hypotheticals.

Since there's something like a usage example in your linked README, that should have been in the question: it's helpful to see, and putting essential parts of the question in external links works badly. I didn't even notice the link was there until after I'd read both the question and all the existing answers, and link rot is also a concern.

Now, looking at your sample usage:

```
#ifndef MYPROJECT_MYCLASS_HPP
#define MYPROJECT_MYCLASS_HPP

#include <namespace_util.hpp>

INLINE_NAMESPACE(myproject, MYPROJECT_MYCLASS_HPP)

using namespace std;

NAMESPACE_EXPORTS

class MyClass {

};

NAMESPACE_END

#endif
```

My first thoughts, approaching this without warning, are:

1. What on earth is this?
2. Oh good, someone else has written a new sub-language in preprocessor. At least it isn't a horribly broken `FOREACH` macro this time.
3. I bet they've written a FOREACH somewhere as well, I'll have to keep an eye out for that.
4. `grep -r '#define private public'` ... no matches, what a relief
5. It's impossible to tell at a glance how to use your class - unless I'm already familiar with your macro idiom, it makes me work harder to figure out it should be called `myproject::MyClass`
6. this doesn't seem to save much time or effort over just writing it out directly, with explanatory comments.

   That is, the macro-free version below isn't much more verbose, is no less clear (they're both confusing the first time you see them, and once you're used to the idiom anyway, the macros are no clearer)

Macro-free version:

```
#ifndef MYPROJECT_MYCLASS_HPP
#define MYPROJECT_MYCLASS_HPP

namespace myproject {
namespace myclass_detail { // external dependencies go here
  using namespace std;     // scope limited to myclass_extern
  namespace publ {         // public declarations in here
    class MyClass {};
  }
}
using namespace myclass_detail::publ;
}

#endif
```

Comment: Thank you for an attempt to understand. Unfortunately, my thoughts have dispersed over the comments to the answers, but generally, yeah, macro-free version can be used, why not? I made macros as a supplement to the idea.

Comment: Never first express your idea using macros - people get hung up on the macro part, and they obscure the code rather than helping. There are lots of reasons to avoid them, and the few exceptions require better justification than _"I thought some names looked long and ugly, but I won't show you those names or any code"_

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of namespaces in C++ is to avoid name clashes between code from different (unrelated) libraries. E.g. libA can define a class or function called `libA::foo` without clashing with `libB::foo`. What's more, version 2 of libA can introduce a name that is already used in libB. The code in libB, as well as other code that uses both libA and libB, will continue to compile and behave the same when we upgrade libA from version 1 to version 2.

When you introduce `using namespace ...` in your code, you lose the protection offered by (proper use of) namespaces. When you upgrade a library whose namespace you imported, your code may fail to compile, due to name clashes. Or (worse), your code may still compile, but behave differently, e.g. because a different function overload is selected during overload resolution.

This problem is not solved by your proposed namespace scheme. When libB depends on libA and imports its namespace, upgrading libA may cause libB to fail to compile (or behave incorrectly).

So, your proposed scheme for the use of namespaces serves a purpose only where the release of dependent libraries are managed collectively. I.e. libB is checked to compile and behave the same whenever libA is modified and/or libB is updated to avoid errors whenever libA is modified. However, in that case it is questionable why these libraries use different namespaces in the first place.

Comment: 1) Quote from you: "The purpose of namespaces in C++ is to avoid name clashes". And that's it. The library stuff you mentioned is the application, which is not the only one.

Comment: 2) I'm not talking about specifically `using namespace <name>`. As for your example, `using <name>` should be just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to share my own thoughts to this problem, as I've been toying with this same idea myself.

Your solution using namespaces works in headers, but it obfuscates compiler error messages. An alternative solution would be this:

```
// header

namespace Internal {
    namespace ProjectNamespace {

        // using declarations, helpers, etc.
        class A { ... };
    }
}

namespace ProjectNamespace {

    using A = Internal::ProjectNamespace::A;
}
```

With this, two things happen: only one unexpected namespace is shown to the user, `Internal`, and isn't super weird looking like `__local__` or `__exports__`. Secondly, the namespaces after `Internal` actually reflect the structure of the API, so the user won't be confused by seeing `__export__` as the enclosing namespace, where the user typically gets the most context around whatever they're using.

It may use a using declaration, but typically you only design one function/class per file, so it will be the same number of lines (1) in many situations. It's worth it IMO to get rid of the second unexpected namespace name.